# New SQL Server table not visible in MS Access Linked Table Manager

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have connected Access with SQL Server using linked table manager. Some tables / views are displayed, some are not.

The recently created view does not show up in the list when I try to add it using linked table manager.

Any ideas how this problem can be solved? Or is there any other way to link recently created view in SQL Server in Access?

Answer (score 1):

For Access 365 you have to go through the pain of clicking Add to add a new datasource, then selecting the new tables/views.  If you give the "new" datasource the same name as your existing one Access is at least smart enough to just append the new tables/views to the existing list.

Comment: Thanks. I found error, I have only missed read permission in the database for user.

Comment: Ah good, glad you found it